# How to add a main method for Quarkus in Kotlin without warning

Tags: kotlin, quarkus

Following the quickstart with Quarkus (3.2.2) in Kotlin (source here: https://quarkus.io/guides/kotlin)

I have defined a main method (translation from Java to Kotlin thanks to Intellij) (source to define the main method: https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#the-main-method)

```
import io.quarkus.runtime.QuarkusApplication
import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain

@QuarkusMain
object Main {
   @JvmStatic
   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       println("Running main method")
       Quarkus.run(*args)
   }
}
```

When building with maven, I have the following warning messages about `unrecommended usage of private members`:

```
mvn package
....
[INFO] --- quarkus:3.2.2.Final:build (default) @ rest-kotlin-quickstart ---
[INFO] [io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor] Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
        - Bean constructor void <init>() on Main
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 1412ms
[info] [Quarkus build analytics] Artifact with group ID: org.acme will not send analytics because it's on the default deny list.
...
```

So far I haven't succeeded to get rid of it.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You shouldn't need an `object` at all. Just make a top-level `main` function, the Kotlin compiler will automatically generate a `MainKt` class around it that you can use to start the application.

Comment: @Jorn sounds like a proper answer :)

Comment: I am confused, If I do that I cannot use the QuarkusMain interface right ? and it won't be picked up, and won't be started as my main method as I would expect it no ?

Comment: I could not make it work the `@QuarkusMain` annotation with a top level function :/ Thanks for the help Jorn :) Maybe when I know more and don't need the QuarkusMain I will use your trick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change worked:

```kotlin
import io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus
import io.quarkus.runtime.annotations.QuarkusMain

@QuarkusMain
class Main {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Running main method")
            Quarkus.run(*args)
        }
    }
}
```

No more warning from the compiler, and the main method is picked up.

Here are the starting logs:

```bash
[info] [Quarkus build analytics] Artifact with group ID: org.acme will not send analytics because it's on the default deny list.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
Running main method
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/
2023-08-04 22:31:11,753 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) rest-kotlin-quickstart 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 3.2.2.Final) started in 1.621s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080

2023-08-04 22:31:11,756 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2023-08-04 22:31:11,757 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [cdi, kotlin, resteasy-reactive, resteasy-reactive-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
```

Side note, I think I need the `@QuarkusMain` annotation because

- I want different main methods depending on the context
- I select them with the `@QuarkusMain(name="mainName")`
- I want quarkus to make different jars where the main method is different